# Creating a check and uncheck all function in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-init

I have few check boxes which I have been check already using ng-init

```
<div class="checkbox">
     <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-init="model.A='A'" ng-model="model.A" ng-true-value="'A'" ng-false-value="'nope'"/>A
     </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
     <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-init="model.A='B'" ng-model="model.B" ng-true-value="'B'" ng-false-value="'nope'"/>B
     </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
     <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-init="model.C='C'" ng-model="model.C" ng-true-value="'C'" ng-false-value="'nope'"/>C
     </label>
</div>
```

What I want is to create a function to make these check boxes check and uncheck when I check a seperate check box, link or a button. Can some one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple as below,

create a link to toggle the checkboxes check status, Here i have created three links

first one is for toggle the checkbox status, second one for uncheck all the checkboxes and last one for check all the checboxes.

```
<a href="#" ng-click="toggleCheck()">toggle check</a> | <a href="#" ng-click="uncheckAll()">uncheck all</a> | <a href="#" ng-click="checkAll()">check all</a>
```

click on uncheck will be handle like below,

```
$scope.uncheckAll = function() {
    $scope.model.A = false;
    $scope.model.B = false;
    $scope.model.C = false;
};
```

assign a value which result in uncheck of the checkboxes.

click on check all will be handle like below,

```
 $scope.checkAll = function() {
     $scope.model.A = 'A';
     $scope.model.B = 'B';
     $scope.model.C = 'C';
};
```

Assign the initial values that result in check status of the checkboxes.

Toggle check like below, if `A` unchecked then all gonna uncheck other vice all are gonna check.

```
$scope.toggleCheck = function() {
    if ($scope.model.A == false) {
        $scope.checkAll();
    } else {
        $scope.uncheckAll();
    }
};
```

here is a [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/j7t1MD1gJGWU6iPFtrIa?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much @K.Toress. This made my day. Thank you again

Comment: :) Glad to help to you `SL` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    //on button click
    var key;

   for(key in $scope.model){
      if(//checked condition){
       $scope.model[key] = key;
      }else{
        $scope.model[key] = 'nope';
      }
    }
```

Comment: What is the checked condition? Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: Based on condition you want to check the checkbox